# Append a value dynamically to js variable name

Tags: javascript

I have some requirement to create a variable name with dynamic id in javascript.

ex:
var id = 1234;//comes dynamically
var min+id = 24;
//later in code i have to use min+id always.
Like above i want to append a value to the variable. Is there a way of doing this.

Thanks,
Kshan

Comment: What do you mean to append a value to the variable?

Comment: I want to add a dynamic value to a variable name.

Instance:
I got a value 24 from webpage.
now i want to create a javascript variable by appending this 24 at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite certain that this is what you're asking, but if you want dynamically named variables, you would set it on an object.

```
var id = 1234;
var varHolder = {};
varHolder['min' + id] = 24;
console.log(varHolder['min1234']);
```

If you need to access it as a normal variable, you would set it on the `window` object. I would recommend against this approach; it just screams design flaw if this is the only way to achieve what you're after

```
var id = 1234;
window['min' + id] = 24;
console.log(min1234);
```

Comment: Yes this is what i am asking but i have to use 'min1234' later in script. 
I cannot write as 'min1234' because i dont know what id i will get from webpage.

Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: create an object to hold all of your dynamic variables, then you can access them the same way that you set them, loop through the keys or values, and much more

Comment: Here you have wrote 'min1234' directly. But i dont know what id i am going to get. So i want something like 'min+id' always as a variable.

Comment: @kshan2k18 writing it out was to show you the keys that are created. you can also access it that same way you set it `console.log(varHolder['min' + id]);`

Comment: @kshan2k18 I don't think you're using the language properly. Maybe try describing how the data is to be used and the proper way of handling that scenario can be suggested.

Comment: @Rhyono I agree. this question is just dripping with bad design

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking about appending the value this could just add to the last

```
var id = '1234'
var xml = value received from webpage;
var combination = id +'' +xml;
```

If this is not your question, please clarify it more to get new solution according to your need